# functions of identically distributed variables are identically distributed

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to prove that $\sum_{i = 1}^n \operatorname{Var}(S(x_i\mid\theta)) = n \operatorname{Var}(S(x_i\mid\theta)$ where $S(x\mid\theta)$ is the score function and I'm working with identically independent variables $X_i$ that form a sample.

Then I wonder if functions of identically distributed variables have the same distribution.

It seems evident (perhaps imposing that the transformation function is continuous) but, what is the formal justification of this fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true, and the function does not need to be continuous, merely measurable. (And that's not much of an assumption... you need to be able to make sense of $f(X)$ as a random variable at all.)

The formal justification is as follows: Let $U$ be some Borel set. Then $$P(f(X)\in U) = P(X\in f^{-1}(U)) = P(Y\in f^{-1}(U)) = P(f(Y)\in U).$$